# SQL command for fetching related data

Tags: c#, sql

I have an HTML form with many input fields like address, zip, from date, to data and complainType as a dropdown list and none of the fields are required HTML fields based on what user inputs I have to fetch the data if any of the fields are not filled I should ignore that field and should fetch data based on filled inputs. How can I write a SQL command where clause? I wrote something like

```
select * 
from table 
where (isnull(address, 0) like 'address') 
  and (isnull(fromDate, 0) > somedate) 
  and (isnull(zip, 0) like 'zip') 
  and (isNull(toDate, 0) < somedate)
```

And I am using this in a C# web method inside SQL command. Please help me with it. I am not sure about stored procedure any idea would be great

Comment: What is your Db layer using? Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it multiple ways. See a sample example below:

```
DECLARE @Customer AS TABLE ([Address] VARCHAR(100),FromDate Date, Zip INT, ToDate Date)

INSERT INTO @Customer
SELECT 'Address1', GETDATE(),68110, DATEADD(DAY,5,GETDATE())
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Address2', GETDATE(),1234, DATEADD(DAY,5,GETDATE())
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Address3', GETDATE(), NULL , DATEADD(DAY,5,GETDATE())
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Address4',  NULL,68110, DATEADD(DAY,5,GETDATE())

select 
* 
from @Customer C
Where
C.[Address] = Coalesce(null, [Address])
AND C.zip = Coalesce(68110, Zip)
```

This [blogpost](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21234/Implementing-Dynamic-WHERE-Clause-in-Static-SQL) explains various other ways you can achieve it.